# "Signature is Invalid" message for AppCenter Webhook request

Tags: github-api, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to write a proxy service between GitHub API and AppCenter API and when I am trying to reroute a standard GitHub API message I am getting a "Signature is invalid" response. 
Here's what I am attempting to send:

```
{
"ref": "refs/heads/xxxx",
"before": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"after": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"created": false,
"deleted": false,
"forced": false,
"base_ref": null,
"compare": "https://github.com/xxxxx",
"commits": [{
    "content": "xxxx"
}],
"head_commit": {
    "content": "xxxx"
},
"repository": {
    "content": "xxxx"
},
"pusher": {
    "content": "xxxx"
},
"organization": {
    "content": "xxxx"
},
"sender": {
    "content": "xxxx"
}
```

}

AppCenter's endpoint is:

```
https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/public/apps/xxxxxxxxxxx/hooks
```

Request's headers are:

```
{
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "User-Agent": "GitHub-Hookshot/xxxxxxxx",
    "X-GitHub-Delivery": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "X-GitHub-Event": "push",
    "X-Hub-Signature": "sha1=xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Here's the response I am getting:

```
{
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "message": "Signature is invalid"
}
```

I've yet to receive a sensible answer from AppCenter, hope somebody already had a similar experience and can answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the value of `X-Hub-Signature`. From [Validating payloads from Github](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/#validating-payloads-from-github), Github uses a HMAC SHA1 between the payload data & the secret string you have put in the webhook section of your repository :

[image]

The signature format (without brackets):

```
sha1={HMAC-SHA1(secret, payload)}
```

A few examples to compute the signature :

- using ruby (from [here](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/#validating-payloads-from-github)) :

  ```
  signature = 'sha1=' + OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1'), ENV['SECRET_TOKEN'], payload_body)
  ```
- using javascript (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106605/2614364)) :

  ```
  var signature = 'sha1=' + CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(payload, environment.secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
  ```